# */ appearing at end of body text in modules

Tags: theming

I am managing a Drupal site and when I add new content (usually events in a calendar) */ always appears at the end of the text field (see example below). I have deleted extra lines and spaces as I thought that might be the cause, but that hasn't worked. I can't locate it in the html but I might be looking in the wrong place. I'm really a novice in all things Drupal. [image]

Comment: Did you search the themes templates folder for `*/`? That is where I would look first.

Comment: Can you use dev tools to inspect source and see where surrounds it in the markup?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a [CSS comment](https://css-tricks.com/swhereets/css/comments-in-css/) end tag. So I am guessing a syntax error. I would inspect the source and find out exactly were the tag is coming from. Then fix the syntax (either by removing the comment tag or adding correct starting comment tag)

Answer (score 0):

This could also be appearing in the php template itself.  You can verify this by switching the site theme to one of the included themes with your Drupal installation and seeing if it still appears; if not, it's definitely in your custom/modified theme.

Then, you can switch your theme back on and inspect the source code of some of the impacted pages to determine if it appears consistently in a particular DOM element/section on the page.

Based on that, you can narrow down and determine if it's inline css in a template file or some other random block comment from javascript or php that isn't properly wrapped.

Presuming you haven't added several custom templates, common templates to check in your theme are:

- html.tpl.php
- page.tpl.php
- node.tpl.php

and any variants of those.